# How far advanced are today's robots with respect to those shown in Real Steel?

Tags: film-techniques, realism, real-steel

Several high-tech robots are shown in the movie [Real Steel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Steel). Robots that can follow *voice commands* and even having *shadow recognition* and *voice recognition* there. I was wondering:

**Do these types of robots really exist today or will exist by 2016 (Remember Noisy Boy was defeated in Rubicon 2016)?**

If not then how was the **filming** of the movie done? It seemed so realistic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fights in Real Steel are all computer animated, as it would be very costly to create and destroy the robots. In this [clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McK90j9GFds) you can see some of the filming to which they add the robots later. They do have the robots but there are just props.

As for the technology, the different parts are all being developed but not yet ready to make fighting robots. Some examples:

- Voice recognition: [Siri](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4D4kRbEdJw)
- Movement: [research](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJmQqC1nHTU)
- Computer vision: [research](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0pM1YUQtf0)

Combining them is the next step but 2016 would be very soon.